# How to change the scheduled_publish_time of a page post via facebook api call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using facebook sdk. i create a post via HTTP Post like this:

```
$param = array('access_token' => XXX,
   'message' => The Message,
  'picture' => The Picture,
  'name'=>The Name,
   'published'=>false,
   'scheduled_publish_time'=>strtotime("The Time"),
   );                  

 $subs = $facebook->api("$pageId/feed", 'POST', $param);
```

It works fine and creates a schedule post on my facebook page now i want to change the schedule time via same method which parameters should be there to get this work done ?